# can't play video on xna

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

i have a problem with plying video with xna, i can't play video with xna. it throw execption.
the exception is: System.InvalidOperationException "An unexpected error has occurred".

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace VideoGameTest1
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D videotexture;
        Video video;
        VideoPlayer videoplayer;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

           // IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            video = Content.Load<Video>("Wildlife");
            videoplayer = new VideoPlayer();

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)  
                this.Exit();

            if (videoplayer.State == MediaState.Stopped) 
            {
                videoplayer.IsLooped = true;
                videoplayer.Play(video);
            }
            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            if (videoplayer.State != MediaState.Stopped) 
            {
                videotexture = videoplayer.GetTexture();
            }

            Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Y, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            if (videotexture != null) 
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(videotexture,screen, Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

the exception was throw here: videoplayer.Play(video);

Comment: Do you know if the WP7 supports the codec the video you are using is encoded in?

Comment: i don't know! but if i play this video on 'windows media player' it is work!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it would be lack of support for codecs. [This site](http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2010/07/28/windows-phone-7-codecs-support-no-hd-video-playback-no-divx-either/) has a list of supported codecs and which ones apply to the XNA framework. If your video is currently encoded in DIVX for example, your PC will play it, but WP7 doesn't support it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that , you are trying to play the video in the update loop and everytime (30 times in a second)  it is trying to access the update it plays video from start . Try placing the video playing code in initialization section . If it works fine , please reply in comment .
If not then too post here in comment.I will look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all!

i fixed it with install new codecs "K-lite codecs"

and now it run.